# ReactJS - Pass Updated Value To Sub-Component Method

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on an environment that is basically set up with a Main Component like this:

```
class MainComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedValues: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedValues } = this.state;
    return (
      // Other components
      <SubComponent selectedValues = {selectedValues} />
      // Other components
    );
  }
}

export default MainComponent;
```

And a Sub Component like this:

```
class SubComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isExporting: false,
      selectedValues: props.selectedValues
    };
  }

  performTask = () => {
    this.setState({ isWorking: true });
    const { selectedValues } = this.state;
    console.log(`Selected Values: ${selectedValues}`);
    fetch('/api/work', {
      method: 'GET'
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
         // Handle the result
         this.setState({ isWorking: false });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({ isWorking: false });
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { isWorking } = this.state;
    return (
      <Button
        bsStyle="primary"
        disabled={isWorking}
        onClick={() => this.performTask()}
      >
        {isWorking ? 'Working...' : 'Work'}
      </Button>
    );
  }
}

SubComponent.propTypes = {
  selectedValues: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)
};

SubComponent.defaultProps = {
  selectedValues: []
};

export default SubComponent;
```

In the Main Component, there are other components at work that can change the `selectedValues`. The functionality I'd like to see is that when the `performTask` method fires, it has the most recent and up to date list of `selectedValues`. With my current setup, `selectedValues` is always an empty list. No matter how many values actually get selected in the Main Component, the list never seems to change in the Sub Component.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I Guess you are getting empty always because in Main component you are doing  <SubComponent selectValues = {selectedValues} /> and in subcomponent you are doing props.selectedValues which must be props.selectValues

Comment: That was actually just an issue with the way I typed up the question. This is a very simplified version of what I'm actually working with, so I had to change some variable names. That must have slipped through the cracks. I've updated the question to fix this error.

Comment: can you share git or code sandbox link?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you 2 of the following methods to check this problem:

- Maybe the state.selectedItems doesn't change at all. You only declare it in the contractor but the value remains, since you didn't setState with other value to it. Maybe it will work if you will refer to `this.props.selectedItems` instead.
- Try to add the function component `WillReceiveProps(newProps)` to the sub component and check the value there.
  If this method doesn't call, it means the selectedItems doesnt change.

Update if some of it works.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**selectedValues** in SubComponent state has not updated since it was set in SubComponent constructor. You may need to call setState again in componentWillReceivedProps in SubComponent